# Accessing an action from a portlet from another

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

So I have an action in a portlet "pA" that prints some info based on the logged user, and now I need that info in another portlet "pB". Instead of duplicating the code, I want to access the action of porlet "pA" from "pB". Is that even possible?

Researching I've managed to get to this at the beginning of "pB":

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>

<liferay-portlet:actionURL var="name" portletName="pA_WAR_war-of-pA">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="view" value="v" />
</liferay-portlet:actionURL>

<h1>URL:: <a href="${name}">${name}</a></h1>
```

But it generates an url for "pB" instead of "pA" ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry so much if this is possible, because it's bad style. If you need the same code in two different portlets, just provide it in a library and use that from both portlets.

A portlet, on the UI layer, should be a closed concept and not have interdependencies with other portlets. A dependency on a common library however is fine.

Comment: I don't need the same code, I want the same data in n places. That's why I want to build an extremely simple web service but it looks like a lost cause in this framework. It's really that foreign of a concept to be able to obtain the logged in user in a fixed url in Liferay?

Comment: It's called "separation of concerns". And of course, you can always get the identity of the currently logged in user everywhere, but your question does not give any hint that this is what you'd like to see. Correct me if I'm wrong...